# Initializing Flutter-Fire flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, initializing

I can't figure out where is the problem output gives me **Connection failed** [Here is the screen out put image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrgsu.png). I'm trying to Initializing FlutterFire (Flutter Web). I'm doing it with the proper guidelines of official documentation https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initializing-flutterfire.But can't figure out where I'm doing the mistake.

When I remove or comment on this part of codes it run.

```
// Check for errors
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Connection failed'),
            );
          }
```

Here is my main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Phatafut Admin Panel',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Phatafut Admin Panel'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // FirebaseServices _services = FirebaseServices();
  var _usernameTextController = TextEditingController();
  var _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // // key:_formKey,
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   elevation: 0.0,
      //   title: Text('Grocery Store Admin Dashboard',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white ),),
      //   centerTitle: true,

      body: FutureBuilder(
        // Initialize FlutterFire:
        future: _initialization,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Check for errors
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Connection failed'),
            );
          }

          // Once complete, show your application
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Color(0xFF84c225), Colors.white],
                    stops: [1.0, 1.0],
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment(0.0, 0.0)),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 350,
                  height: 400,
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 6,
                    shape: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 2),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                                  Text(
                                    'Grocery App ADMIN',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                        fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    controller: _usernameTextController,
                                    validator: (value) {
                                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Enter UserName';
                                      }

                                      return null;
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'UserName',
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 20, right: 20),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                                    .primaryColor,
                                                width: 2))),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    controller: _passwordTextController,
                                    validator: (value) {
                                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Enter Password';
                                      }
                                      if (value.length < 6) {
                                        return 'Minimum 6 character required';
                                      }

                                      return null;
                                    },
                                    obscureText: false,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Minimum 6 Characters',
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key_sharp),
                                        hintText: 'Password',
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 20, right: 20),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                                    .primaryColor,
                                                width: 2))),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TextButton(
                                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.white,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                        onSurface: Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                          //  _login(username: _usernameTextController.text, password: _passwordTextController.text);
                                        }
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Login',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

          // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="admin_panel">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <title>admin_panel</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>

       <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-analytics.js";

        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "********",
          authDomain: "********",
          projectId: "*********",
          storageBucket: "************",
          messagingSenderId: "******",
          appId: "**************",
          measurementId: "******"
        };
      
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      </script>

  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>

<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: admin_panel
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these lines under `<body>` in your `index.html`, the documentation suggests using version `8.6.1` this way:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

And don't forget running `flutter build web` before deploying.